# MySQL using CASE WHEN with IN subquery

Tags: mysql

Here is a brief explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish; my query follows below.

I have two tables, one with 500 products `product_limit500`, and another with orders `order_limit1000`.

My goal is to create a table with all 500 products for each order, all in the same order (as in `order one followed by all other products`, and then `order two followed by the products in the same order`).

This is the query that I have tried using.

```
SELECT 
  r1.order_id, 
  r1.product_id, 
  r1.product_name,
  CASE WHEN p1.product_id IN (SELECT 
                                r2.product_id 
                              FROM 
                                order_limit1000 r2 
                              WHERE 
                                r2.order_id = r1.order_id) THEN 's'
  ELSE '?'
  END as 'torf'
FROM 
  order_limit1000 r1, 
  product_limit500 p1;
```

And this is the result as of right now.

```
  order_id  product_id  product_name    torf
   5    13176   Bag of Organic Bananas  ?
   5    13176   Bag of Organic Bananas  s
   5    13176   Bag of Organic Bananas  ?
   5    13176   Bag of Organic Bananas  ?
   5    13176   Bag of Organic Bananas  s
   5    13176   Bag of Organic Bananas  ?
   5    13176   Bag of Organic Bananas  ?
   5    13176   Bag of Organic Bananas  ?
   5    13176   Bag of Organic Bananas  ?
   5    13176   Bag of Organic Bananas  ?
   5    13176   Bag of Organic Bananas  s
   5    13176   Bag of Organic Bananas  ?
   ...
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

...

Right now I'm using a view with 500 `products` and 1000 rows of `orders`, I'm still thinking what the final size for `orders`, probably something like 500k to 1mi rows. But the datset I`m using has something like 4.5mi rows.

The expected result would be something like the following.

```
 order_id   product_id  product_name    torf
    5           123        tomatoes      s
    5           124        limes         ?
    ...
    100         123        tomatoes      ?
    100         124        limes         ?
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimum sample of data and the expected output from it, this will help a lot to understand the goal. Also, add the tables schema.

Comment: Sample data and expected result will be helpful.. And avoid using comma for join.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PLEASE** don't use commas between table names, and certainly don't do this as a substitute for `cross join`. I'm not sure why you would want every product against every order, but to do that you do need a full Cartesian product and hence you need a cross join.

```
SELECT
    r1.order_id
  , p1.product_id
  , p1.product_name
  , CASE
        WHEN r1.product_id = p1.product_id THEN 's'
        ELSE '?'
    END AS 'torf'
FROM order_limit1000 r1
CROSS JOIN product_limit500 p1
ORDER BY
    r1.order_id
  , p1.product_id
  , p1.product_name
```

Given that the order table already has a product_id in it, you do not need another correlated subquery to test if you should output 's' or '?'. nb: I am assuming that product name comes from the product table, not the order table.

```
  order_id   R1.product_id   P1.product_id   product_name   torf  
 ---------- --------------- --------------- -------------- ------ 
         5             123             123   tomatoes       s     << r1.product_id = p1.product_id
         5                             124   limes          ?     
       ...                                                        
       100                             123   tomatoes       ?     
       100                             124   limes          ?
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.